# Analytics advanced segment filter is showing home page results

Tags: google-analytics, filtering, segments

Using a simple filter, Page contains /test but the results displayed include /, /blog, /photos pages.

Any idea why this would be happening on such a simple segment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, just to avoid confusion, I'd recommend not naming advanced segments as filters, as theese are completely different things. You have advanced segmentation and advanced filtering on profiles.

When using an advanced segment to segment sessions to a specific page, theese sessions will include the WHOLE session. So, if a session (or visit, it is the same thing) would navigate /, /blog and /photos and you'd create a segment to only contain /blog, you'd still see pageviews for /, /blog and /photos. That is because the session matches your segment, so the WHOLE session will be included.

What you want to do is to create an include only **filter** (not a segment) which includes only visits to /test. This way, only the pageview of a particular session will be saved and not the whole session.

Comment: Thanks @MrSponge If i didn't want to setup lots of filters, would a quick way around this would be to use the advanced search option? Obviously this would be only a temporary solution.

Comment: That could be a quick work-around, sure. Or a customized report which only filters /test and then pull the metrics that you want. But using advanced filters is the most sure-fire way.